# Требуются ли здесь эти запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

А она, при виде такой роскоши, просто удивилась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Комментарий к ответу (продолжение)**

Пожалуйста, не сердитесь на меня, **я вовсе не критикую ваш ответ,** не в нем дело. Вы для меня человек новый, и мне хочется понять, насколько интересный.  Поэтому я не буду обсуждать каждый ваш ответ или что-то **ждать от ваших ответов**. Возможно, я вообще никогда больше не буду обращаться к вам лично. Но сейчас попробуем  **закончить разговор.**

Вот, к примеру, я читаю в правилах: **обособление обстоятельств факультативное**. А зачем дальше-то читать, если понимать факультативность как вседозволенность:  обособляю **что хочу и когда хочу**.  Но почему-то Розенталь приводит разные примеры, да и вопросов по обособлению обстоятельств на форуме всегда очень много.  Неужели нашим пользователям  **недоступна информация**, которую вы приводите в § 74?

И вот вопрос **о границах факультативности**, на который  вы не захотели ответить, представляется мне важным. Возьмем пример из Розенталя: «***Ранней весной, по неведению своему, местные жители почти не ловят рыбы»***. Мне кажется, что обособление этого оборота выходит за границы факультативности  и обособлять его нужно обязательно. А вот в моем примере, наоборот, обособление нежелательно: «***При виде такой роскоши она просто удивилась, но не более того».***

Конечно, смысл  сказанного – это главное в тексте, но  чтобы обозначить этот смысл, автор должен **подобрать соответствующую структуру предложения**. К сожалению, об этом не написано в правилах.  Соответственно,  если мы объясняем знаки препинания в готовом предложении с уже определенной структурой, то должны ее учитывать.

Ведь **факторов**, влияющих на обособление, на самом деле много: распространенность и позиция оборота, структура самого предложения, дополнительные смысловые оттенки и т.д. Поэтому факультативность предполагает проведение **дополнительного анализа**, склоняющего нас к тому или другому решению.